# How to make atomic add with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am searching for a way to make atomic or non-vector addition, or other operations in `numpy` with one operator, not Python loop

Say i have following `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np 


arr = np.zeros(4)

ids = np.array([1,2,1])

adds = np.array([1,2,3,4])

arr[ids] +=adds[ids]
'''
for  x in ids:
    arr[x] +=adds[x]
 '''   

print(arr )
```

How do I implement the commended out code? The result of this add is not correct, it is like i am adding ti the arr[1] position only once.
Is there a `numpy` function to properly perform this operation?

Ok, is it possible also to do that:

```
ids = np.array([0,1,2,1])

adds = np.array([1,2,3,4])

for  i, x in enumerate(ids):
    arr[x] +=adds[i]
```

with one numpy operation? This was the main question.

Comment: Look at `np.add.at` - it does an unbuffer version of `+=`.

Comment: ok thanks that i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to return the unique indices together with the index counts. Then you can use the counts to multiply with the r.h.s. of the add operation:

```
i, n = np.unique(ids, return_counts=True)
arr[i] += n*adds[i]
```

Comment: wait sorry i wanted not that(see modified question)ids = np.array([0,1,2,1])

adds = np.array([1,2,3,4])

for  i, x in enumerate(ids):
    arr[x] +=adds[i]